# Gridview PageIndexChanging not Firing

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, page-index-changed

I am writing my own event handler for `GridView` in `PageIndexChanging event`, I didn't explicit set the `DataSourceID` for my `GridView`, here is my code:

Code for GridView data binding:

```
protected void DetailsView_DataBound (object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{
    Customer cust = (Customer)DetailsView.DataItem;
    this.GridView.DataSource = cust.Orders;
    this.GridView.DataBind();
}
```

This part of the code allows me to show order details in `GridView` when data bound with `DetailsView`. Then I write my own `GridView_PageIndexChanging event handler` and DOES NOT work for me:

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex();
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

If I click the next page number, the website shows nothing.  But if I change `GridView.DataBind()` to `DataBind()` The paging works.

Anyone has any idea why the second `Databind` method works and what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

the second databind is DataBind(Page.DataBind) which refrence to current page binds all page controls and its child controls.

Comment: This is the part confuse me. I am binding data with my GridView, why should I call Page.DataBind() method instead to make to databind work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set allowPaging="True" of gridview. if not then set it to true.

Comment: Yes, I did.I set AllowPaging="ture" and onpageindexchanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging". In my situation, I only need to change GridView.DataBind() method to DataBind() method to make my paging codes work.